# Laptop seems pressing keyboard on its own

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard

About weeks ago, my Lenovo Ideapad Y700 started to press its keyboard button on its own.

I tested keyboard event using this [key event tester website](https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) and turns out my laptop is keep pressing keydown button (Sometimes keyup).

At first, I press keyup on the keyboard a few times and fixed it but it will happen again when I restarted the laptop. The symptom grew worse every day and now this "fix" is not working anymore.

I tried these things but still not fixed it:

1. I uninstalled HID Keyboard Device and Standard Keyboard PS/2 Driver and restart the laptop. It reinstalled themselves automatically and the funny thing is the HID Keyboard Device seems to increase itself, at first it was 2 drivers, they are 5 now.
2. I plugged in my external keyboard, pressing keyup a few times but still have the same issue.
3. I used Malwarebytes scan both of my hard disk partitions but found nothing.
4. I tried to enter the safe mode by using the Recovery menu of Windows 10. The issue still happens in the safe mode.

Few notes, the keypress issue does not happen when I am in any BIOS-like menu (including Lenovo BIOS menu, Windows Advanced Options Menu, etc.) but it starts to happen again when I successfully launched the Windows.

Comment: Which button and always the same? It might be a hardware problem.

Comment: I would try to clean the whole keyboard

Comment: change with another keyboard to check, or plug the keyboard to another computer to check.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with one particular key or keys, the problem is probably
hardware.

A good cleaning of the keyboard will solve the problem of sticky keys.
Be careful, as some keyboards are fragile.